# HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA2.2 with Hibernate and a MySql database. I have a simple Entity (Account) and when I try to send a simple query, I get a hibernate Exception and crashes because it goes out of memory. Any help in tracking this issue will be great.

Thanks.
Entity: Account.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private Long accountId;

    @Column(name = "accountName")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name="startDate")
    private LocalDate startDate;

    @Column(name="startBalance")
    private double startBalance;

    @Embedded
    private Summary summary = new Summary();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="portfolioId")
    private Portfolio portfolio;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="account", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Asset> assets = new HashSet<Asset>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "account", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "startDate")
    private Map<LocalDate, AccountCalculation> accountCalculations = new HashMap<LocalDate, AccountCalculation>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "account", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "year")
    private Map<Integer, AccountSummary> accountSummaries = new HashMap<Integer, AccountSummary>();

    public Account() {
        super();
    }
```

Query to get All the Accounts

```
public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
    TypedQuery<Account> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Account a", Account.class);
    List<Account> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="portfoliomanager" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/PMDevDS</jta-data-source>
        <!-- <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error trace:

```
16:56:18,220 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-1) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
17:00:30,129 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
17:00:30,131 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) GC overhead limit exceeded
17:00:30,134 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (default task-1) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
17:00:55,899 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component AccountService for method public java.util.List com.poth.portfoliomanager.service.AccountService.getAllAccounts(): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:258)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:374)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:627)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at com.poth.portfoliomanager.service.AccountService$$$view13.getAllAccounts(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at com.poth.portfoliomanager.service.AccountService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getAllAccounts(Unknown Source)
    at com.poth.portfoliomanager.view.queryBean.queryAccount(queryBean.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:54)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1396)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at com.poth.portfoliomanager.service.AccountService.getAllAccounts(AccountService.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:249)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1277)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1149)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:960)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 177 more
```

Comment: How many accounts, assets and portfolios do you have?  Should they all fit in memory?

Comment: I just have 1 portfolio, 5 accounts and about 60 assets in total. This is a very small application and they all fit in memory

Comment: I'm missing what's gone awry for you but I'd throw a `query.SetMaxResults(2)` in there and see what happens.

Comment: I will try that in the morning and let you know. It is very weird why this is happening

Comment: Derek S. it still does not work. I set the maximum results to 2 and I get the exact same Exception

Comment: Is it possible there is a circular reference in your data?  Try just getting the count and see if that comes back.

Comment: I dont see a circular reference within the Account Entity. I did test with (String query = "SELECT a from Account a WHERE a.portfolio = " + pId + " AND a.accountName = " + "'"
     + accountName + "'";) and it worked fine. I am puzzled at why the other query is going into an infinite loop

Comment: If that doesn't do it I think you set show SQL and format SQL true in your config and try timing the query in MySQL to see what you are getting.

Comment: There is an issue somewhere in how you are joining the tables and you are getting too much back. It isn't at the account level most likely but one of your other mailed tables.  Removing them one at a time might help but it is probably a combination of two.

Comment: Let me try and may be I will create a separate test app and try it there

Comment: Derek, I experimented with enabling SQL and formatting it and I noticed that for a simple getAllAccounts query, the hibernate query is quite large more than 100 lines. Is that normal?

Comment: I think the way you are combining several pieces of information is having an unexpected complication. Try commenting some out and see if you can narrow it down. Or try just pulling the lower level objects like assets.

Comment: The problem is with Eager fetching. Switching to Lazy speeds up the query but there are issues with LazyInitializationException!

Comment: I still contend your data model is creating many relationships you don't intend and you will want to iron that out.  I'd guess AccountCalculation or AccountSummary is connecting to Assets many times over but can't be sure as you only shared the Account table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle db it may cause due to lack of grant of your user on your database. If your database user has no grant on the table, you cannot access the table. You can try to grant the user on your table for the necessary operations like below.

```
GRANT
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
ON
your_schema_name.account
TO
your_db_user;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).